# how to use getlinecount() in textview android

Tags: android, textview

i want to know how many line in my text view.
i already set mytextview text, then i want to get how many line it take in mytextview.

i use mytextview.getLineCount() but it didn't work.
it always return 0.

can someone helpme.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [textview.getLineCount always 0 in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android)

Answer (score -10, accepted):

thanks for all. i solved it already. i use thread to get the linecount just like this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(textView.getLineCount() == 0){

    }
    countLine = textView.getLineCount(); 

}
```

hope this will help if you have same problem.
best regard.

Comment: This code is dangerous if line count "IS" 0. The thread will loop forever.

Comment: this will do the trick for above problem--> replace `while loop` with `while(textView.getLineCount() == 0 && ! textView.getText().toString().isEmpty());`

Answer (score 31):

You need to post method for fetching the lines counts. Here is the sample code

```
imageCaption.setText("Text Here");
imageCaption.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int lineCount    = imageCaption.getLineCount();

        Log.v("LINE_NUMBERS", lineCount+"");
    }
});
```

Comment: getLineCount will still return 0 in this scenario, at least when it's inside of a ListView.

Answer (score 2):

you can check the TextView parameters inside onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int c = tv1.getLineCount();
    tv1.getLineBounds(0, rect);
    tv1.getLineBounds(1, rect);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

public int getLineCount ()

Since: API Level 1

Return the number of lines of text, or **returns 0 if the internal Layout has not been built.**

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link.

[Android Edittext: Get LineCount in an Activity's onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086321/android-edittext-get-linecount-in-an-activitys-oncreate)

tv.getLineCount(), will always retirn 0, if internal layout is not created yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Following will provide the lines count of the textview at the same place you set tv.setText().

```
int maxTextViewWidth="ENTER MAX WIDTH HERE";

tv.setText("hello\nhow are you?");

int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxTextViewWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

tv.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

int lineCount=tv.getLineCount();
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. I know you've seen others, but code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.